# What is the recommended way to do validation in Spring MVC for both Thymeleaf and REST

Tags: spring, rest, validation, spring-mvc

In case you have an application using the latest versions of the modules supplied by the Spring ecosystem, what would be the recommended way to do validation in a project which supplies both "standard" webpages, using Thymeleaf, as well as Rest Controllers for third parties?

Most of the Spring MVC + Thymeleaf recommendations use Form-based validations. These are quite limited already, and it might be that you want to separate your web project from your core (business services) project, with a dependency from your web to your core. But it seems to me that would require you to do validation in both your MVC as well as your services layer.

The Rest Controllers recommendations mostly rely on @ExceptionHandler, or using ResponseEntity which does enable you to throw exceptions from the services layer easily.

I assume a good approach would be to throw custom exceptions from the Services (core package) layer and catch them in the MVC layer, with the exceptions containing both a key, and an error message (the key "mappable" to one of your form values, or just being a general error message). After that transforming them into key:value pairs and pushing them into your view, but I assume that's not optimal either.

What are the recommendations to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with Hibernate validator?

Comment: Well, where would you put the validation annotations on? The same class of your domain layer you already have annotated for JPA?